# OpenStreetMap Library

Tags: c++, openstreetmap

I am looking to parse OpenStreetMap PBF (binary) files through C++.  The only constraint is that the library must be Windows compatible.  There is a library out there ([libosm](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/travelingsales/index.php?title=LibOSM)), but one of the authors said it was unlikely to work on Windows because of POSIX calls.  Does anyone know of a C++ PBF parser for Windows?

Comment: It also appears to be a Java library...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are loads of libraries listed at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks, of which, [LibOSMScout](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Libosmscout) looks the most promising.